# Calculate values of resistors in a given BJT amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

I have the circuit shown below and i have limited resistors to make it work. The LED's rated current is 10mA so Ic = 10mA. I know that beta for the transistor is 100.

The resistors are (I have 2 of each):

- 47ohm
- 100ohm
- 470ohm
- 10k
- 15k
- 20k potentiometer

[image]

Comment: You mention "amplifier", an amplifier must have an input and an output, your circuit has no output. There's a LED, why do you need a LED? It says (100\$\Omega\$) near the LED, what does that mean? Why have a resistor between - of 1V source and ground? What is this circuit supposed to do?

Comment: Also, mark your components with reference numbers like R1, R2 etc. so that anyone trying to explain something has a reference to refer to.

Comment: Alright thank you for the tips. Its my first question, i will improve next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many resistors. Most of them can be 0Ω (short circuits).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQJm7X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since this has the appearance of a homework problem, I'll leave it to you to explain how this circuit works and what its limitations, if any, might be.